# Sleep machine during matlab simulation

Tags: matlab

I'm running matlab simulations on my laptop that take a lot of time (days!). sometimes I need to move with my laptop, this requires sleeping or hibernating.

Is there a way to save the state of simulation or pause it during sleeping?

Comment: Have you tried just suspending/sleeping/closing the lid as usual? This has worked fine for me on every (Mac) laptop I've owned. The machine sleeps when I close the lid and the simulation continues running when I open it up again.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/pause.html
check this if it can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great article [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5343) about *checkpointing* MATLAB programs. The basic idea is that you sprinkle points throughout your program (or simulation) that periodically save the state (i.e. the important variables) at that point to a file. At each point, the program checks to see whether a file exists: if it does, it loads it in and proceeds to the next checkpoint - otherwise it does whatever bit of the simulation it needs to, and then proceeds to the next checkpoint.

In this way you can sleep/hibernate your laptop whenever you want, then start it up again it will continue from the last uncompleted checkpoint.

Hope that helps!